# msbuild, defining Conditional Compilation Symbols

Tags: .net, msbuild, compiler-options

I'm possibly just blind, but is there a command line to specify conditional compilation symbols in MSBUILD?

I currently have this Line in my buildscript:

```
SET MSBUILD=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe
SET CONFIG=Debug
%MSBUILD% /p:Configuration=%CONFIG% /p:OutputPath=..\..\output source\MyProject\MyProject.csproj
```

And I'd like to add a condition. In Visual Studio, i can just go into Project Properties => Build => Conditional compilation symbols, but I have not seen that option for msbuild?

Bonus Karma if you know if I can completely override all symbols already specified in the .csproj files to make sure that only the conditionals from my Buildscript go in.

Comment: And BTW, this is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296147/msbuild-conditional-compilation because the other question has the same title but the answer only includes Visual Studio/Project File modification.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/95bf6b1d-9dae-48ba-b56d-08fa5ae26563/)? (most info is in the penultimate post)

```
/p:DefineConstants="MYSYMBOL1;MYSYMBOL2"
```

Comment: Added the Code, that was it, thanks! It overrides all Constants that may be defined in the .csproj file, which is good as well.

Comment: For this to work for me, I was forced to add this to the command line: /t:Rebuild

Comment: using xbuild from os x terminal I get `MSBUILD: error MSBUILD0005: Invalid syntax. Property name and value expected as <prop name>=[<prop value>]`

Comment: Worked great.  /p:DefineConstants="QCBUILD"
My solution has lots of projects in it.  This seems to be solution global.  Does anyone want to point me to how to get a solution global conditional compilation symbol while using the Visual Studio (not command line)?

Comment: Is there any way to append to the existing defines?

Comment: Note that this will *replace* the existing defines, so if you were relying on things like NETCOREAPP or NETFRAMEWORK being defined, you'll lose those. To append to the existing defines, it's better to add a property in your `.csproj` file like: `<DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);FOO;BAR</DefineConstants>`.

Comment: As of MS Build from Visual Studio 2019, this doesn't seem to work for a C++ project - the defined symbols don't get to the command line, passed to the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 22):

I had to use a space instead of a semicolon a la this post by Björn Lasar: http://www.linqinpark.net/2009/01/13/MSBuildWithMultipleDefineConstants.aspx

**Update: the blog has disappeared;** [retrieved via Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20100406211501/http://www.linqinpark.net/CategoryView,category,MSBuild.aspx):

> Recently I had to use MSBuild directly to automate some builds. I also had to configure some preprocessor defines based upon a configuration. This is usually done by an Argument like this

```
"/p:DefineConstants=MY_PREPROC_FLAG"
```

> Nothing special here since there are enough comments on the web about that. Today I needed one Flag more and I used the commandline syntax similar to how I knew it from the IDE:

```
"/p:DefineConstants=MY_PREPROC_FLAG;YET_ANOTHER_FLAG"
```

> but this one didn't work.
>
> So the point is that if you want to support multiple defines to a project by commandline you'll have to separate them by simple spaces...

```
"/p:DefineConstants=MY_PREPROC_FLAG YET_ANOTHER_FLAG"
```

> and it will be added to the (semicolon-separated) Defines from the IDE. 
>   Good to know I think...

Comment: How do you test for the existence of these symbols?  I tried if '$(SIGN_ASSEMBLY)' == '' goto :exit but if the symbol doesn't exist, you get the same empty string.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury one always uses the presence of a value, and its specific value, i.e. `== "True"` - not sure what you mean with the goto exit in msbuild - the equivalent would be to put a `Condition` on the `<Task` and/or on the task invocation e.g. `<Exec Condtion="$(SignAssembly)=='True' ...`

Answer (score 6):

`/p:DefineConstants` is an all or nothing deal.

If you just want to turn off trace symbol, you can't just do it with: `msbuild /p:DefineTrace=false`

You have to define something to override all the symbols already defined: `msbuild /p:DefineConstants="RANDOM-SYMBOL"`

Thanks Michael Stum point this hidden rule out
[I have also wrote a blog about it --- dead link](http://www.tomatosoft.biz/blog/2011/11/11/msbuild-override-symbols-already-definded-in-csproj-file/)

Comment: "all the symbols" is really important here. If you use /p: DefineConstants to define a constant you will lose all the other defined constant in a project. DefineConstants  should contain all the constants need in the project you can not mix and match constants defined in project and defined with DefineConstants

Answer (score 1):

What is said in the answers is valid for `C#` code, and also for ASP.NET "codebehind" C# code. For **ASP.NET web projects**, if you want to do conditional compilation in the ASPX pages as well, it works a bit differently to conditionally render HTML on the page (note I've removed `MasterPageFile="..." AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="..." Inherits="..."` which you usually have in the `<%@ ... %>` declaration as well):

```
<%@ Page Title="MyPage" Language="C#" CompilerOptions="/d:DebugSym1;DebugSym2" %>

<% #if DebugSym1 %>         
    <h4>Section1</h4>
<% #else %>
    <h4>(Section 1 skipped)</h4>
<% #endif %>

<% #if DebugSym2 %>         
    <h4>Section2</h4>
<% #else %>
    <h4>(Section 2 skipped)</h4>
<% #endif %>
```

If you remove `DebugSym1` or `DebugSym2` from the `CompilerOptions`, then the `#else` part of the relevant `#if` statement is rendered.

I thought this was worth mentioning for completeness of this topic and can save you time. More you can find in this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/16/conditional-compilation-constants-and-asp.net.aspx), if you're interested.