# Passing DefineConstants argument to msbuild not working

Tags: c++, msbuild, macros, preprocessor-directive

I have an empty c++ project containing one file which says

```
#ifndef FOO
#error
#endif
void main(){}
```

I want to compile this using msbuild by passing the constant FOO to msbuild. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714668/how-do-you-pass-conditional-compilation-symbols-defineconstants-to-msbuild) it can be done with the command

```
$ msbuild /property:DefineConstants=FOO /t:Rebuild
```

in some shell. However, this gives me the error

```
Project "C:\Users\Chiel.tenBrinke\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1.sln" on node 1 (Rebuild target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|x64".
The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
Project "C:\Users\Chiel.tenBrinke\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1.sln" (1) is building "C:\Users\Chiel.tenBrinke\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\Project1.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (Rebuild target(s)).
_PrepareForClean:
  Deleting file "x64\Debug\Project1.tlog\Project1.lastbuildstate".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Touching "x64\Debug\Project1.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\CL.exe /c /ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /sdl /Od /D _MBCS /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"x64\Debug\\" /Fd"x64\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue Test.cpp
  Test.cpp
c:\users\chiel.tenbrinke\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\project1\project1\test.h(3): fatal error C1189: #error: [C:\Users\Chiel.tenBrinke\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\Project1.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Chiel.tenBrinke\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\Project1.vcxproj" (Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Chiel.tenBrinke\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1.sln" (Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\Chiel.tenBrinke\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1.sln" (Rebuild target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Chiel.tenBrinke\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\Project1.vcxproj" (Rebuild target) (2) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  c:\users\chiel.tenbrinke\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\project1\project1\test.h(3): fatal error C1189: #error: [C:\Users\Chiel.tenBrinke\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\Project1.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

I tried all kind of combinations like

```
$ msbuild /property:DefineConstants="FOO=1" /t:Rebuild
```

but that didn't help.

Using the command

```
$ msbuild /property:PreprocessorDefinitions="FOO" /t:Rebuild
```

gives the same output.

Comment: "Compilation constants" are a VB.NET and C# concept, languages that quite intentionally avoided macros.  In C++ you define macros with the `<PreprocessorDefinitions>` element.  Generates the `/D` command line argument to the compiler.  Easy to see if you use the IDE to set them and look what happens with the .vcxproj file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference. However, `msbuild /property:PreprocessorDefinitions="FOO" /t:Rebuild` doesn't work out of the box...

Comment: Well, all we know is what happens when you tried to do it the wrong way, we can't see what happened when you tried to do it correctly.  Some notes about why you are trying to punish yourself like this would be wise as well.

Comment: Answer updated. I want to see if a solution compiles when a certain preprocessor directive is defined. Passing it on the commandline as described in the linked post seemed to be an easy way to do this. Your wording about me punishing myself suggests that you think this is the wrong way though xD. Is it?

Comment: Ok, so in conclusion, DefineConstants is not supported for C++ projects, and the PreprocessorDefinitions alternative can not be passed from the commandline.. (At least that's what that linked post says). Will mark this as duplicate then.