# How to define compilation symbols only when profiling?

Tags: c#, profiling, c-preprocessor, symbols, conditional-compilation

I'd like to define a compilation symbol like *PROFILE* only when I'm profiling a C# project in Visual Studio. In a normal debug or release build it should not be defined.

So the code between #if and #endif gets only compiled when profiling.

```
#if PROFILE
  DataCollection.StartProfile(ProfileLevel.Process, DataCollection.CurrentId); 
#endif
```

It should be a compile time check, no runtime check. The reason is that some of our team have no profiler on their PCs (not included in VS 2012 Standard) and we would like the code to compile on any system without changes.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new **configuration**:

- Click **Build** then select **Configuration Manager**.
- Click **Active solution configuration** and select **New**.
- Type `Profile` in **Name** and select which configuration will be used as template (for profiling I guess `Release`).
- Confirm with **OK**, it'll create new configurations named `Profile` for each project in your solution.
- Open properties of each project, and in the Build tab add `PROFILE` symbol in **Conditional compilation symbols** then save properties.

Now when you build the `Profile` configuration the `PROFILE` symbol will be defined. I suggest you take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479979/msbuild-defining-conditional-compilation-symbols) too, if you automate your builds you may keep your `PROFILE` symbol out of the solution using `MSBuild` properties via command-line (I suppose you do not build for profiling very often).

**EDIT**
With *configuration* you can do that but it won't save you from a broken reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler.dll`). What I suggest is to move all this code to **another library** that you'll ship to them compiled. There you'll expose just a method:

```
public static class ProfilingHelpers
{
    [Conditional("PROFILE")]
    public static void StartProfiling()
    {
        DataCollection.StartProfile(ProfileLevel.Process, DataCollection.CurrentId);
    }
}
```

In your code you'll always call it but it'll be executed only when `PROFILE` is defined (so you won't need to add a new configuration to each project but to one DLL only).