# Conditional Compilation of c# solution using a batch file

Tags: c#, batch-file, compilation

I need a batch file that will conditionally compile my c# solution, I tried finding but nothing relevant retrieved.

Comment: What kind of condition do you mean? Could you give an example?

Comment: By condition I meant #define regions with in the source code, what I want is I could just give the name of the region as input in my batch script and build it accordingly

Comment: possible duplicate of [msbuild, defining Conditional Compilation Symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479979/msbuild-defining-conditional-compilation-symbols)

Comment: The link @AlexeiLevenkov mentions points to MSBUILD documentation. In my answer I assumed you were looking for the C# compiler command line options.

Comment: I need an external batch file urgently, help me out with that

Answer (score 3):

```
csc /define:DEBUG /optimize /out:File2.exe *.cs
```

and

```
void Foo()
{
#if DEBUG
    PrintDebugInfo();
#endif
    Bar();
}
```

This defines the constant DEBUG so File2.exe will contain the call to PrintDebugInfo.

See the [MSDN csc.exe commandline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx) options for more details.

Comment: +0: Note that you answered slightly different question - "how to compile single CS file with define", not whole solution.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - correct. user3044705 will decide what the correct answer is/what he needs. I am happy to delete my answer if it doesn't answer the question and was answered in the duplicate you mentioned.

Comment: when I use the above code in my batch file(which I want it to be an external batch file) csc is not recognized as a command

Comment: @user3044705 - Make sure you use the Visual Studio Command prompt/environment. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes but still the code is exiting with code 1

Comment: Any other information than code 1?

Comment: No, for an external batch file say at my dekstop, how do I navigate to my solution directory which I want to compile as per your given solution using csc

Comment: Either set all the environment variables in the batch file similar to the VS environment or pass the correct path to each file. Note that csc will NOT let you build a solution (sln) see the link provided by Alexei for that.