# Azure Devops: Conditional compilation symbols

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to find a way to inject some conditional compilation symbols to an Azure Pipeline which builds a project.

I have several pipelines targeting different clients / envs, and I would like to be able things like this in my C#:

```
#if <VARIABLE>
#endif
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: The answer can be found in this similar post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479979/msbuild-defining-conditional-compilation-symbols

I needed "/p:DefineConstants"

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can inject the conditional compilation symbols to an Azure Pipeline. It is very much similar to what you would have done in your local environment. In Azure Pipelines, you can publish your symbols to Azure Artifacts symbol server using the ***Index sources and publish symbols*** task as mentioned in this [Publish symbols for debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/symbols?view=azure-devops#set-up-visual-studio) document.

We generally use [**MSBuild task in an Azure DevOps**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops) pipeline using a remote agent to work with the conditional compilation symbols. You can also use the **[Visual Studio Build Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops)** for the same. But remember that locally we usually build with **Debug** mode. In Azure it builds with **release** mode as configured. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69139494/what-is-the-proper-way-to-debug-azure-pipeline-failed-builds-when-local-builds-s) by for more information about it.

Which ever task you use, it should pickup your conditional compilation symbols and to do so make sure that they are setup for the 'Release' configuration not only for debug.

[image: conditional]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479979/msbuild-defining-conditional-compilation-symbols  has the answer. I needed  "/p:DefineConstants"