# Build an C# application such that it consume either s3 or blob based on Cloud it's running

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, azure

I am working to build C# Web Application. My Web Application can be deployed on Azure as well as on AWS.

Challenge is like my application needs Blob storage like Azure Blob and AWS S3.

Now I am using Repository pattern for now and I have added Azure SDK as well as AWS SDK.

But requirement is like to build 2 images so that image for Azure should have Azure SDK and Image for AWS should have AWS SDK only.

Is there any specific approach to tackle such scenarios?

In C++, we have compiler flag so that we can skip some portion of code from compilation. Is there any such option available in C# while compiling code to IL.

Note: If yes, then I will like to use 2 flags so that build one code for Azure and another for AWS.

Comment: I think you might be after [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by defining custom constants, see [msbuild, defining Conditional Compilation Symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479979/msbuild-defining-conditional-compilation-symbols) and others.

Create three class libraries:

- `YourLib.Abstractions`: storage interfaces
- `YourLib.AWS`: implementations for AWS
- `YourLib.Azure`: implementations for Azure

Then your main application, in the .csproj, conditionally include references:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="../YourLib.Abstractions/YourLib.Abstractions.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('AWS_BLOBS'))">
   <ProjectReference Include="../YourLib.AWS/YourLib.AWS.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('AZURE_BLOBS'))">
   <ProjectReference Include="../YourLib.Azure/YourLib.Azure.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And in your code, call the appropriate dependency injection logic:

```cs
#if AWS_BLOBS
services.AddAwsBlobs();
#endif

#if AZURE_BLOBS
services.AddAzureBlobs();
#endif
```

Then when compiling:

```
dotnet build /p:DefineConstants="AWS_BLOBS"
```

You can also create solution-level build configurations ("Debug: AWS", "Debug: Azure") and define the constants there.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for the same.. I will accept answer after trying it. Thanks again.